# The French word "about"

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions

I have only studied French for a few weeks. I have been looking for the word "about" that fits the context below but I end up with all kind of Words that I do not feel like they fit in. I have finally found "environ" and I am curious if it would be correct to use it as I do in the sentence? Or perhaps there is a better word?

Je voudrais vous raconter environ ma sœur.

Comment: Tu voudrais nous parler de ta sœur.

Comment: Sometimes, "about" is "*à propos de*". You could say "Je voudrais vous parler de quelque chose à propos de ma soeur". (I want to tell you something about my sister).

Comment: I have run into á propos de also but I am uncertain (and that makes it a little difficult) which word or phrase is most commonly used.

Comment: Adding to what Stéphane said and is correct. If you're using "about" at the beggining of the sentence "About my sister..." the translation would be "A propos de ma sœur..." or "En parlant de ma soeur.." and "De ma soeur" would be impossible.

Comment: Welcome on french.SE btw :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As is often the case, there's no 1 to 1 translation of *about* in French.

*Environ* only translates as *about* when it marks an approximate quantity:

> She was **about** ten = Elle avait dix ans **environ** // Elle avait **environ** dix ans

When *about* is an adverb, it translates as an adverb or an adverbial phrase in French too:

> I was **about** to leave = J'étais **sur le point** de partir

When *about* is a preposition marking the topic of a conversation, a speech, a book, or the like, there are three main options:

**de**: It only has this meaning with a few verbs, but this includes a very important one: *parler* (also *discuter* and *causer*, all essentially meaning *speak about*). Your sentence could thus translate to:

> Je voudrais vous parler **de** ma sœur - I'd like to speak to you **about** my sister

**sur**: This is the general preposition that's used with most other verbs (and it can be used with *parler* too, although with a different meaning in some dialects)

> J'aurais aimé vous dire quelque mots **sur** ma sœur - I'd have liked to tell you a few words **about** my sister

**à propos (de)**: unlike the other two (the most and fifth most used prepositions in French), it's unambiguous and can only mean *about*. It's however quite  a bit clunkier, clocking in at four syllables and is mostly thus used for maximum clarity or in verb-less sentence fragments:

> J'aurais aimé vous dire quelque mots **à propos de** ma sœur

Even then it has a meaning that's not shared by English's *about*:

> **À propos de** ta sœur, elle se l'est enfin payée, sa liseuse Kindle ? - **Speaking of** your sister, did she finally buy herself a Kindle?

*À propos* can also mean *by the way*.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "*environ*" would be an incorrect translation. It only means "about" in the sense of "approximately", "more or less", or "thereabouts".

For the sense of about that's about "relating to", which you're using in this sentence, a better translation would be "*à propos de*" :

> I would like to tell you something about my sister.
>   Je voudrais vous raconter quelque chose **à propos de** ma soeur.

[Relevant dictionnary entry](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/about).

Comment: Thanks for elaborating and explaining. This is something that is not covered in my book yet since I am still novice. Merci beaucoup.